# d3.js selectable tree diagram

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I try to implement a selectable tree diagram. I am using [this sample](http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/8375092)

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <title>Tree Example</title>

    <style>

    .node {
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .node circle {
      fill: #fff;
      stroke: steelblue;
      stroke-width: 3px;
    }

    .node text {
      font: 12px sans-serif;
    }

    .link {
      fill: none;
      stroke: #ccc;
      stroke-width: 2px;
    }

    </style>

  </head>

  <body>

<!-- load the d3.js library --> 
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>

<script>

var treeData = [
  {
    "name": "Top Level",
    "parent": "null",
    "children": [
      {
        "name": "Level 2: A",
        "parent": "Top Level",
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "Son of A",
            "parent": "Level 2: A"
          },
          {
            "name": "Daughter of A",
            "parent": "Level 2: A"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "Level 2: B",
        "parent": "Top Level"
      }
    ]
  }
];


// ************** Generate the tree diagram  *****************
var margin = {top: 20, right: 120, bottom: 20, left: 120},
    width = 960 - margin.right - margin.left,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var i = 0,
    duration = 750,
    root;

var tree = d3.layout.tree()
    .size([height, width]);

var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
    .projection(function(d) { return [d.y, d.x]; });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

root = treeData[0];
root.x0 = height / 2;
root.y0 = 0;

update(root);

d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", "500px");

function update(source) {

  // Compute the new tree layout.
  var nodes = tree.nodes(root).reverse(),
      links = tree.links(nodes);

  // Normalize for fixed-depth.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) { d.y = d.depth * 180; });

  // Update the nodes…
  var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
      .data(nodes, function(d) { return d.id || (d.id = ++i); });

  // Enter any new nodes at the parent's previous position.
  var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")"; })
      .on("click", click);

  nodeEnter.append("circle")
      .attr("r", 1e-6)
      .style("fill", function(d) { return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff"; });

  nodeEnter.append("text")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? -13 : 13; })
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .attr("text-anchor", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start"; })
      .text(function(d) { return d.name; })
      .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

  // Transition nodes to their new position.
  var nodeUpdate = node.transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")"; });

  nodeUpdate.select("circle")
      .attr("r", 10)
      .style("fill", function(d) { return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff"; });

  nodeUpdate.select("text")
      .style("fill-opacity", 1);

  // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
  var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")"; })
      .remove();

  nodeExit.select("circle")
      .attr("r", 1e-6);

  nodeExit.select("text")
      .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

  // Update the links…
  var link = svg.selectAll("path.link")
      .data(links, function(d) { return d.target.id; });

  // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
  link.enter().insert("path", "g")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .attr("d", function(d) {
        var o = {x: source.x0, y: source.y0};
        return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
      });

  // Transition links to their new position.
  link.transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("d", diagonal);

  // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
  link.exit().transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("d", function(d) {
        var o = {x: source.x, y: source.y};
        return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
      })
      .remove();

  // Stash the old positions for transition.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) {
    d.x0 = d.x;
    d.y0 = d.y;
  });
}

// Toggle children on click.
function click(d) {
  if (d.children) {
    d._children = d.children;
    d.children = null;
  } else {
    d.children = d._children;
    d._children = null;
  }
  update(d);
}

</script>

  </body>
</html>
```

This will create a result like this:

[tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SFxvk.png)

I want to render a check box below the circles to make the nodes selectable, I added

```
      nodeEnter.append("input")
  .attr("type", "checkbox").style("position", "absolute")
  .style("top", "320")
  .style("left", "150")
;
```

But the above code didn't render any checkboxes beside the texts. How do I make the tree selectable?

Answer (score 1):

try using `foreignObject`.write click event on `circle` instead of entire `g` object.

```html
     <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">

        <title>Tree Example</title>

        <style>

        .node {
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        .node circle {
          fill: #fff;
          stroke: steelblue;
          stroke-width: 3px;
        }

        .node text {
          font: 12px sans-serif;
        }

        .link {
          fill: none;
          stroke: #ccc;
          stroke-width: 2px;
        }

        </style>

      </head>

      <body>

    <!-- load the d3.js library --> 
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>

    <script>

    var treeData = [
      {
        "name": "Top Level",
        "parent": "null",
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "Level 2: A",
            "parent": "Top Level",
            "children": [
              {
                "name": "Son of A",
                "parent": "Level 2: A"
              },
              {
                "name": "Daughter of A",
                "parent": "Level 2: A"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "name": "Level 2: B",
            "parent": "Top Level"
          }
        ]
      }
    ];


    // ************** Generate the tree diagram  *****************
    var margin = {top: 20, right: 120, bottom: 20, left: 120},
        width = 960 - margin.right - margin.left,
        height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var i = 0,
        duration = 750,
        root;

    var tree = d3.layout.tree()
        .size([height, width]);

    var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
        .projection(function(d) { return [d.y, d.x]; });

    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    root = treeData[0];
    root.x0 = height / 2;
    root.y0 = 0;

    update(root);

    d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", "500px");

    function update(source) {

      // Compute the new tree layout.
      var nodes = tree.nodes(root).reverse(),
          links = tree.links(nodes);

      // Normalize for fixed-depth.
      nodes.forEach(function(d) { d.y = d.depth * 180; });

      // Update the nodes…
      var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
          .data(nodes, function(d) { return d.id || (d.id = ++i); });
       
      // Enter any new nodes at the parent's previous position.
      var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
          .attr("class", "node")
          .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")"; })
          ;
     
      nodeEnter.append("circle")
          .attr("r", 1e-6)
          .style("fill", function(d) { return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff"; }).on("click", click);
      
      nodeEnter.append("text")
          .attr("x", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? -13 : 13; })
          .attr("dy", ".35em")
          .attr("text-anchor", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start"; })
          .text(function(d) { return d.name; })
          .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);
      nodeEnter.append("foreignObject")
      .html("<input type=checkbox id='check'></input>").style("position", "absolute")
      .style("top", "320")
      .style("left", "150")
    ;//use foreignObject to get check boxes
      // Transition nodes to their new position.
      var nodeUpdate = node.transition()
          .duration(duration)
          .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")"; });

      nodeUpdate.select("circle")
          .attr("r", 10)
          .style("fill", function(d) { return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff"; });

      nodeUpdate.select("text")
          .style("fill-opacity", 1);

      // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
      var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
          .duration(duration)
          .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")"; })
          .remove();

      nodeExit.select("circle")
          .attr("r", 1e-6);

      nodeExit.select("text")
          .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

      // Update the links…
      var link = svg.selectAll("path.link")
          .data(links, function(d) { return d.target.id; });

      // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
      link.enter().insert("path", "g")
          .attr("class", "link")
          .attr("d", function(d) {
            var o = {x: source.x0, y: source.y0};
            return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
          });

      // Transition links to their new position.
      link.transition()
          .duration(duration)
          .attr("d", diagonal);

      // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
      link.exit().transition()
          .duration(duration)
          .attr("d", function(d) {
            var o = {x: source.x, y: source.y};
            return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
          })
          .remove();

      // Stash the old positions for transition.
      nodes.forEach(function(d) {
        d.x0 = d.x;
        d.y0 = d.y;
      });
    }

    // Toggle children on click.
    function click(d) {
      if (d.children) {
        d._children = d.children;
        d.children = null;
      } else {
        d.children = d._children;
        d._children = null;
      }
      update(d);
    }

    </script>

      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Thanks, any idea how can I prevent the tree to collapse/expand when user clicks on the checkbox?